# How to make bars in bar charts fill all the gaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a problem with matplotlib.pyplot.bar in which bars can have only constant width, but I want to make a plot, where bars are located between two points. As we can see in the figure, points have different distances, and I want to fill all the gaps with bars. Sorry if this was asked before, I couldn't find it.

[image]

so basically I want to bar of the point I have a width of the distance between `i` and `i+1`, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it provided a solution to your problem. Please also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example creates a bar plot with 7 height values and 8 boundaries. The difference between successive boundaries is used as the bar widths. Bars are default aligned with their centers, but when working with uneven widths, `align='edge'` is needed.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

bounds = np.array([21000, 31000, 41000, 53000, 62000, 73000, 81000, 90000])
heights = np.random.randint(50000, 120000, len(bounds) - 1)

plt.bar(bounds[:-1], heights, width=np.diff(bounds), align='edge', color='crimson', ec='navy')
# plt.xticks(bounds) # to have the boundaries as x ticks
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]